# Lift LinearLayout on click

Tags: android, material-design, elevation

In `res/animator` directory I have lift_on_touch.xml file which should lift linear layout on click (**NOT** press or hold but just short **CLICK**). The file itself

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <objectAnimator android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
            android:propertyName="elevation"
            android:valueTo="6dp"
            android:valueType="floatType" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <objectAnimator android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
            android:propertyName="elevation"
            android:valueTo="2dp"
            android:valueType="floatType" />
    </item>
</selector>
```

But when I apply stateListAnimator to my linear layout in layout xml like this `android:stateListAnimator="@animator/lift_on_touch"` it only works (i.e. lifts) when I press and hold my linear layout **BUT NOT** when I just click it. I also have `android:clickable="true"` in my linear layout.

Question: How to lift my linear layout **on click**?

Comment: Have you tried changing `duration` property to 50 or 30? Because `@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime` [it's a pretty long time for a click event](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/config.xml#119)

Comment: @MatPag yes, I have, but it still lifts when I press and hold, but this time just faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i think you should use `onTouchListner()` instead of `onClickListner`
>   bcs here you can get the event of Hold and unHold of View by using
>   below code

```
linearLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);

                switch(action) {
                    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) :
                        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Action was DOWN");
                        // Hold Event will invoke continues 
                        return true;
                    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) :
                        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was MOVE");
                        return true;
                    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) :
                        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was UP");
                        // here unhold event will invoke 
                        return true;
                    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) :
                        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was CANCEL");
                        return true;
                    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) :
                        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Movement occurred outside bounds " +
                                "of current screen element");
                        return true;

                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```